# Reason for (win) x64-calling convention restrictions in epilogues

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, abi, seh

I'm trying to understand the actual reasoning behind the restrictions that the x64 calling convention has on epilogues, at least on Windows? Quoting from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/prolog-and-epilog?view=msvc-170):

> The epilog code must follow a strict set of rules for the unwind code
> to reliably unwind through exceptions and interrupts. These rules
> reduce the amount of unwind data required, because no extra data is
> needed to describe each epilog. Instead, the unwind code can determine
> that an epilog is being executed by scanning forward through a code
> stream to identify an epilog.

I get what they are saying, but I don't understand the practical implications, at least for exceptions. Given the limited set of instructions that a valid epilogue can contain, I don't see what type of exceptions could even occur in the first place. If we look at the possible instructions in the epilogue, with their most complex example:

```
   lea      RSP, -128[R13]
    ; epilogue proper starts here
    add      RSP, fixed-allocation-size
    pop      R13
    pop      R14
    pop      R15
    ret
```

We can't really do anything that would result in an exception being thrown. pop could result in stack-underflow, but if that's happening, we don't have a valid return-address left, and thus no valid unwind could occur. Or if RSP points to some invalid memory address, where we would once again not really have a valid target for ret.
So we would, at most, invoke the top-level SEH handler for the particular function that the epilogue belongs to, in such a scenario.

Is the reason really just for interrupts (which I have no knowledge or understand of)? Or am I missing how an x64-compliant epilogue could trigger an exception? If the reasoning was just to not have exceptions in epilogues, they wouldn't need the whole machinery of scanning the code-stream to determine if an exception occurs within an epilogue.

As for why I'm asking this: I'm doing some trickery for my native codes stack-switching, that includes generating technically invalid epilogues (and prologs, to an extent). I'm trying to make sure that I don't run into unexpected side-effects, as long as I make sure not to allow recoverable exceptions to occur there (for a normal user-mode application).

Comment: Raymond Chen has given the example of an I/O error on a page-fault to page in code from a failing HD or CDROM as a way for an SEH to be delivered a basically any instruction boundary.  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190111-00/?p=100685

Comment: @PeterCordes So for that case, since I don't handle that type of exception explicitely (unlike in the example). If the exception would be triggered during an epilogue, I would crash eigther way. The difference is that a proper epilogue would give me a sensible stack-track to where I was, while an improper epilogue will just be cut off after the current call?

Comment: I don't know Windows that well; hopefully @Raymond Chen will answer this or post a link in comments.

Comment: My understanding of SEH may be entirely wrong but as I understand it, the unwind code essentially parses the instruction stream to emulate the epilogue, in order to safely unwind to the exception handler. So it isn't about an exception being caused by the epilogue. It's about the unwind code being able to find, parse, and emulate the epilogue if an exception was caused somewhere in this function or one of its subfunctions.

Comment: @Homer512 Not quite. x64 allows for multiple epilogues, so the actual effect of an epilogue cannot be/are not determined by scanning (which one would it be?). The actual effects of an unwind are described in the unwind-data, and simulated from there. What I'm refering to is strictly about unwinding out of an active epilogue, as the doc describes.